# add a column to data frame using pandas concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have "train_df" data frame which:

```
print(train_df.shape)
```

returns (997, 600).

now I want to concatenate a column to this data frame which:

```
print(len(local_df["target"]))
```

returns 997.

so it seems that everything is ok with the dimensions.

but the problem is that:

```
final_df = pd.concat([train_df, local_df["target"]], axis=1)
print(final_df.shape)
```

returns (1000, 601).
while it should be (997, 601).

Do you know what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `assign` a numpy array as a new column.

```
final_df = train_df.assign(target=local_df["target"].values)
```

For pandas >= 0.24,

```
final_df = train_df.assign(target=local_df["target"].to_numpy())
```

Answer (score 4):

I think problem is with different index values, so solution is create same by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True`:

```
final_df = pd.concat([train_df.reset_index(drop=True), 
                     local_df["target"].reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
print(final_df.shape)
```

Or set index of `local_df` by `train_df.index`:

```
final_df = pd.concat([train_df, 
                     local_df["target"].set_index(train_df.index)], axis=1)
print(final_df.shape)
```

Comment: This is the actual answer, since it concatenates based on the indices. A mismatch will yield extra rows for the number of mismatched rows

Answer (score 0):

How about join?:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'c':[232,543,562]})
print(df.reset_index(drop=True).join(df2.reset_index(drop=True), how='left'))
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c
0  1  4  232
1  2  5  543
2  3  6  562
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is most efficient

Adding a new column `y` to a dataframe `df` from another dataframe `df2` which has this column `y`

```
 df = df.assign(y=df2["y"].reset_index(drop=True))
```